# How do I get Visual Studio 2017 to hit Script Debugging break points after Add Docker Support is done?

Tags: visual-studio, docker, visual-studio-debugging

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.1 application with Angular. I am trying to use Visual Studio 2017 15.9.7 to debug its TypeScript.

In order to simplify troubleshooting of this issue, I created a brand new ASP.NET Core 2.1 Empty Web Application. I added:

```
app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

to the Startup.cs's Configure method.

I added an index.html with a link to a js/index.js file with a few simple lines of code in it:

```
var a = 1;
var b = 2;
var c = a + b;
alert("Hello from index.js. var c=" + c);
```

I placed a breakpoint at line 3. I chose Google Chrome from the "IIS Express" debugging drop down and hit the green arrow labeled "IIS Express" to run it. Chrome paused before showing the alert message until I clicked "Step Into" enough times to show the alert and then the page's html. This Script Debugging behavior also worked successfully with the Microsoft Edge browser after hitting the browser's refresh button.

I then created a new git branch called "AddDocker", right-clicked the project in solution explorer, and chose "Add Docker Support".

Now clicking the newly changed "Docker" button next to the green debug arrow, launches the site in Edge (even if Chrome is selected) and will load the web page with all of the javascript loaded, no longer hitting the break points. The break point icon is now hollow and shows the message "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document" upon mouse over.

The behavior I am expecting at this point in working through my trouble shooting sample project is for Visual Studio 2017 to hit the javascript breakpoints when debugging with Chrome or Edge even after Docker Support has been added.

Can anyone help me achieve this?

Note: it would be easy enough for me to just debug with IIS instead of the Docker debug button in my real project, but that doesn't work either. I figured I would start small and test the Script Debugging features in a brand new project, gradually adding elements and troubleshooting each problem, until I have a sample project where Visual Studio 2017's Script Debugging works with all the technologies I'm using including Docker-compose, Angular, and TypeScript. Thereafter, I can apply my fixes to the real project.

Thanks a lot!